# How to add OpenVino setupvars.sh into PyCharm project?

Tags: pycharm, openvino

I would like to add OpenVino setupvars.sh into a PyCharm project?

I'm working on a project usig OpenVino and in order to use OpenVino right now I am using following bash script in .bashrc

```
source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
```

However, I would like to work on the project using PyCharm which make easier to handle the project as it gets bigger.

How we can use OpenVino in a PyCharm project.

Answer (score 3):

Work for me on Windows 10:
Run CMD, then:

> "\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\bin\setupvars.bat"
>
> "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\bin\pycharm64.exe"

On macOS work too. Dont know about linux.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for Ubuntu

Add the setupvars.sh in bashrc file.
Open terminal and write

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add these lines to the end of the file

```
# <<< Initialize Intel Vino environment variables <<<
source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
# <<< Initialize Intel Vino environment variables <<<
```

Save and open new terminal, now the current terminal has loaded the environment variables. You can verify that if you see this line in the terminal

```
[setupvars.sh] OpenVINO environment initialized
```

Open pycharm from the terminal by executing

```
pycharm-community
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set this by pointing to the correct Python Interpreter in PyCharm. To get the current working Python environment, type the following lines of code in your local system.

> python

```
>>>import sys
>>> sys.executable
<PYTHON PATH>
```

Make a note of this Python path and add it to File -> Settings -> Python Interpreter (In pycharm).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this, however, I was not able to import openvino in PyCharm projects. Right now, I'm using PyCharm for development but I run source codes using terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I think we have met the same question.

Here is my solution. Hope can help you :)

### Make Your Own Interpreter File

1. Make a new file such as python-custom.

   ```
    touch python-custom
   ```
2. Open the file you just made.

   ```
    vim python-custom
   ```
3. Save the following code into the file.

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

    args=$@

    # needed environment path
    . /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh

    # Path of your normal python path
    # You can find it by "which python", "which python3" or any python you used
    /usr/bin/python3 $args
   ```
4. Add executable permissions for it.

   ```
    chmod +x python-custom
   ```
5. Add a new interpreter in Pycharm.

   File -- Settings -- Project Interpreter
6. When you choose the interpreter, use "/path/to/python-custom" instead of "/usr/bin/python3".

Comment: What is the "/opt/nuclio/common" path? I don't have it on my Mac

Comment: @user1315621 That is a mistake. The path is used for my project. Just remove it and have a try. (I have re-edited it) This shell is going to run your python codes with the shell including your environment, such as setupvars.sh here, instead of normal "/usr/bin/python"